# What are the d and q axes for induction machine?

Tags: motor, generator, three-phase, induction-motor, synchronous-motor

What are the d and q axes for an induction machine (physical meaning)? I understand them for a synchronous machine but how are they defined for an IM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as synchronous machine. Physically they are not rotated in relation to the stator with rotor angle, but with rotor flux vector which has to be estimated using a mathematical model of the respective IM.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please answer these two questions for me if you happen to have worked on Doubly-fed induction generators. Does the grid side converter in a DFIG absorb/provide reactive power or is it reactive neutral? Also, what can we say about reactive power exchange in the rotor side converter?

Comment: @Pikachu So sorry, but DFIG is some new tech that I don't know.